# Reactjs render JSX with dynamic text value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS and I have the following problem that I can't find a solution to:

At the point just prior to render I would like to replace a space between two words with anything that will force a line break. So far everything I try doesn't work. I've read the React documentation which may be suggesting I'm dealing with a '[JSX Gotchas](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html)'

```
let strReturn = "\u000A";//<br/>//\u000D

// for example this.props.label could have a value of "Big Bid"

//  now remove space between 'Big Bid' and replace with <br/>
let str = this.props.label.replace(/ /, strReturn );

return <div className={this.props.className}>{str}</div>
```

Presently what is rendered to screen includes text of say Big`<br/>`Bid.

If there are any ReactJS pros that could show me the best way of dealing with this issue I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There couple ways how you can solve this issue

1. use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

   ```
    let str = this.props.label.replace(/ /, '<br>');
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: str} } />;
   ```

   [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47852/)
2. split string and then wrap each line to tag, for instance `<p>`

   ```
    let text = this.props.label.split(/ /).map((text, index) => {
      return <p key={ index }>{ text }</p>
    });

   <div>
     { text }
   </div>;
   ```

   [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47854/)

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I'd actually go the route of being explicit with what you're trying to achieve, rather than relying on Unicode insertion tricks, or disabling escaping etc.

I would just split the string according to whitespace, and then, build a list of elements from it.